# Is it possible to slip out of the CC field in a mail conversation?

Tags: email

Sometimes mail conversations get out of hand. If **you're in the CC field** and folks keep hitting **reply-all** you'll keep getting all the e-mails. Now suppose you've lost interest in this mail conversation and any follow-ups (perhaps it turned into a *"favorite christmas song mailthread"*): **how can you *slip out* of this thread?**

The only thing I could think of was ask a colleague that's also in the thread to "sacrifice" him/herself by hitting reply-all and removing your address from the CC field. That's not really a solution though, because it's not something you can do *yourself*.

PS. In my specific situation we all have inboxes on the same Exchange server (and my client is MS Outlook 2010) - but preferably an answer would also work if non-exchange mailboxes are involved.

Comment: Your best bet would be to hit reply-all and tell everyone to leave your email address off of any further exchanges.

Comment: Thx for the suggesion. Alas, it's kind of similar to the solution I mentioned trying; I'd prefer a solution where I can take action *myself* to slip out of the thread.

Comment: Set up a filter that looks for incoming messages with the subject line and your email address in the CC list and when it finds one, deletes the message or routes it to the trash.

Comment: Reply to all and say your most favourite christmas song of all time is Rage Against The Machine's [Killing In The Name Of](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/8423340.stm). They'll understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have identified the only practical way of doing this as it's a human problem rather than a computer problem.

People often hit "reply-all" without realising and/or checking who's actually in the cc list, so unless someone makes the effort to trim the list or only hit "reply" you are stuck.

You could set up a filter that moves all e-mails you are cc'd on to a different folder. This would remove the immediate problem but has the drawback that you could miss important e-mails as well - unless you checked that folder regularly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to **reply all** and mess with the **reply-to address**. This might work. But hacky. And not even sure how easy it is.

The neater solution would I suppose be similar to gmails **mute** feature. You can see if your client has a feature/plugin which does this. **Outlook appears to** have something similar, from this [About.com page](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/How_to_Delete_and_Mute_a_Conversation_in_Outlook.htm) ([not exactly the same though](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/be-careful-with-ignore-feature-in-outlook-2010/))

A person has gone to the trouble of coding up an [exact emulation of mute](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/gmail-mute-feature-outlook/) for outlook 2003.

Comment: Thx! I don't mind being hacky, as I'm *really* not interested in people's favorite xmas songs...